# Finding domain of analyticity for complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a complex logarithm $\ Log(e^z + i)$, to find its domain of analyticity do I only solve for when $e^z + i = 0$ or am I not allowed to have negative numbers either. My textbook doesn't explain or have many questions of this sort.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\log (\ldots)$ and not $\text{Log} (\ldots)$?

Comment: The principal branch of logarithm is not defined at negative reals. Kaster's answer computes the relevant values of $z$.

Comment: Whoops Log I'll fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyway, if you want to find domain of analyticity for $\text{Log} \left ( e^z + i\right )$, then you need to follow this theorem:

The domain of analyticity of any function $f(z) = \text{Log}\left[g(z)\right]$, where $g(z)$ is analytic, will be the set of points $z$ such that $g(z)$ is defined and $g(z)$ does not belong to the set $\left \{z = x + iy\ |\ −\infty < x \leq 0, y = 0\right \}$.

In you case $g(z) = e^z+i$. You can do next
$$
e^z+i = e^{x+iy}+i=e^x \left ( \cos y + i \sin y\right ) + i = e^x \cos y + i \left ( e^x \sin y + 1\right )
$$
So final answer would be
$$
\text{Domain of analyticity:} \quad z \in \left \{ z = x + iy \ | \ e^x \cos y > 0, e^x \sin y \neq -1 \right \}
$$
Fist condition yields $\left \{ x \in \mathbb R;\ y \in \left ( -\frac \pi 2 + 2\pi k, \frac \pi 2 + 2\pi k\right ),\ k \in \mathbb Z \right \}$.

As for the second one, I don't think it can be solved analytically, but it has infinite number of roots.

Comment: Somewhere in mid-argument, most of your $y$ turned into $x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Gosh, you're right, I'll revise it in a bit

Comment: So you can only solve for e^z + i can't equal 0 and not values where e^z + i > 0?

Comment: @DJ_ I didn't get your last statement. Procedure is to find values of the function where its real part is positive and imaginary part isn't equal to $0$.

Comment: Oh right, never mind.